# Google Spredsheet - Copy files to another folder in TeamDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I try to copy some movies from a Google Drive folder to another Folder and rename the file by using a script in a Spreadsheet. (other options than spreadsheets are also welcome, but this seems to be easyest). I got access on both folders.

a) is working as it should, makeing a copy of the file in the same folder;

b) is also doing a copy but still in the same folder and not in the destination-folder;

c) giving error:

> "cannot find method makeCopy(string,string)"

```
function copyFile() {
var FileToCopy=DriveApp.getFileById('12B-zfprxgazbZ4JFxyrqhYveofYATzC1');
FileToCopy.makeCopy()
}


function copyFile() {
var FileToCopy=DriveApp.getFileById('12B-zfprxgazbZ4JFxyrqhYveofYATzC1');
var Destination = "1yC_nDk9VQLHBAkYNwNkRucfxp6yFBIV1";
FileToCopy.makeCopy(Destination)
}

function copyFile() {
var FileToCopy=DriveApp.getFileById('12B-zfprxgazbZ4JFxyrqhYveofYATzC1');
var Destination = "1yC_nDk9VQLHBAkYNwNkRucfxp6yFBIV1";
var Filename = "newFile.mp4";
FileToCopy.makeCopy(Filename, Destination)
}
```

Comment: Hi, Ed! `Destination` should be a `Folder` class instance, not a `String` (and currently you use an Id)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var Destination = "1yC_nDk9VQLHBAkYNwNkRucfxp6yFBIV1";
```

try

```
var Destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1yC_nDk9VQLHBAkYNwNkRucfxp6yFBIV1");
```

If you see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)), you need to pass the folder and not the ID of the destination folder.

Comment: this did work - thanks a lot. very much appreshiated your help